# Cisco AnyConnect VPN client - prevent connecting as work network

Tags: windows-7, vpn, windows-firewall, cisco-vpn-client

From Windows 7 I'm using "**Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 3.0**" to connect to our corporate network.

Every time I establish the VPN connection Windows will set the type as "**work network**". I don't want this. So I go to "**network and sharing center**" and manually / interactively change it to "**public network**".
But I have to repeat it for every new VPN connection.

- Is there any way to make *Windows* remember / persist this configuration?
- Can it be configured in the *VPN client*?
- Do our IT admins need to change something at *server* end?

**Motivation:**
A "work network" per default uses different firewall settings that allows for stuff like "network discovery" and "file shares". But I absolutely don't want this for the VPN connection!
I just need "remote desktop" (mstsc). That's all.

**Additional info:**
Our IT admins claimed this would be Windows default behaviour and there was nothing we could do about it: Windows would always initiate a VPN connection as "work network". Based on this statement I assume this is a "general" issue and went ahead posting here (at superuser.com).
From what I've read so far it could be related to Microsoft / Windows **NLA** and related configuration parameters?

**Update1:**
The situation has become even worse. Previously i would establish the VPN connection and then manually change to "public network". But now - after some time running with VPN connection - the network type *automatically* switches back to "work network". This means: I need to frequently check the network type and adjust when required.
Help! How can i stop this?

**Update2:**
still the same problem with Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 3.1.04072

**Update3:**
still the same problem with Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 3.1.05182

---

**observations so far:**

it seems the following registry locations are playing a role:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures]
```

in particular:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{<Network GUID>]
"Category"=dword:00000000
"CategoryType"=dword:00000000
```

where:

```
0 = Public
1 = Private (includes "Home" and "Work")
2 = Domain
```

and in my case the "Category" keeps flipping back from "0" to "1".
the question is: why?
and how can i prevent this?

Comment: But if the VPN as-is allows you to do RDP, why do you need to change it?  That's not making any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what has worked for me:

- start the VPN client and connect
- now run `secpol.msc`
- go to the node **`Network List Manager Policies`**
- open the properties of your remote domain network
- go to the tab "Network Location"
- change "Location type" to `Public`
- (optional?) change "User permissions" to "User cannot change location"

From now on windows will retain the network type as "public".
[image]

Technically speaking this will populate entries below the following:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\
```

Those policies take precedence over the following entries - which (due to whatever logic) may change dynamically:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\
```

--
Confirmed with:
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 3.1.06079 @ Win7 x64

Update:
still working fine with Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 3.1.10010 @ Win7 x64

Comment: This works with v4.3 too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following process:

- Navigate to each key in regedit:

  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles`
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures`
- Change the value to 0
- Right click on the key name, then select `Permissions`
- Click Administrators
- Click `Deny` for each checkbox below